# Regex supposed to replace double newline replaces single ones in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to remove all empty lines preceding a '}' in my code, using C#. This is what I am using, trying to replace multiple occurrences of '\r\n' preceding a '}' by a single one:

`Regex.Replace(result, "[\r\n]{2,}\\s*}", "\r\n}");`

It is generally working (removed space characters are a non-issue in my case) but I have a strange case of false positive and I do not understand why it is a match for this regex. It is the following expression:

```
            var test = new[]
            {
                1,
                2,
                3,
            };
```

The result is:

```
            var test = new[]
            {
                1,
                2,
                3,
};
```

When I debug my code, the input is the following:

```
            var test = new[]\r\n            {\r\n                1,\r\n                2,\r\n                3,\r\n            };
```

So, definitely no double line! and 100% reproductibility. Can someone help me to understand the issue, please?

When I test it on regex sites, it is NOT a match. In my code, it is.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `[\r\n]` is a character class, it matches any character inside, so `\r\n` will match twice. Use `(\r\n){2,}` instead.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, I should have checked what I was doing better and before losing hours on it lol. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `[\r\n]{2,}` matches two or more `\r` or `\n` symbols.

Use

```cs
Regex.Replace(result, @"(?>\r\n?|\n){2,}\s*(?=})", "\r\n");
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?>                      match (and do not backtrack afterwards)
                           (at least 2 times (matching the most
                           amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n?                      '\n' (newline) (optional (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2,}                    end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```